# Delete button using Fetch API delete

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch, crud

i have a question. I am creating simple CRUD application with backend on Java EE and oracle database.

I need to create button to delete object. REST intefrace for delte is .../rest/product/idofproduct

I am using class with Fetch API

```
class App{

deleteProduct(id){
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/productdb-0.1/rest/product/'+ id , {
        method: 'delete'
    })
        .then(r=> r.json());
}
}
```

than i have a fucnction.js where i have

```
    let deleteApp = new App();
    let remove = document.getElementById('productList');
    remove.addEventListener('submit',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id = document.getElementById('delete').getAttribute('data');

    })
```

I am trying to map it on button inside

```
            <tr>
            <td class="text-center">${product.productName}</td>
            <td class="text-center">${product.priceVC} $ / ${product.priceMC} $</td>
            <td class="text-right"><input id="delete" data="${product.id}"type="submit" value="X Delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"></td>
        </tr>
```

but its not working, dont know what could be wrong.

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Where is your #productList in your code ?

Comment: its table `            <tbody id="productList">

            </tbody>`

Comment: It's work https://jsfiddle.net/r3ym6Lxa/1/ 
What is the error displayed? Are your sure with this line ? `<td class="text-center">${product.priceVC} $ / ${product.priceMC} $</td>`

Comment: yes with this, i am just showing data from json, its no problem there, but button is not working, just prompt pop up when i click it, but nothing is deleted

Comment: You need to call this function : deleteProduct(id) in your remove.addEventListener('submit')

Comment: When i try to do `remove.addEventListener('submit', deleteProduct(id) ,function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let id = document.getElementById('delete').getAttribute('data-id');
 
  }) ` i get Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteProduct is not defined

Comment: Like this `remove.addEventListener('submit',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id = document.getElementById('delete').getAttribute('data');
        deleteApp.deleteProduct(id);
    })`